# django models without primary key and id

Tags: django, model

I use two primary keys.

In database, this does not result in duplicate errors unless both values are duplicated.

But I don't know how to solve this problem in django model.

When the primary key is removed and used, an id column is created. But I do not want this.

Using unique_together results in an error because the primary key is duplicated.

Is there any way to solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why not use id? You can simply ignore it if you want to use some other fields which are unique_together for queries. But in any case you need a field which is a primary key and is unique.